# Ghost email subscribe is giving “Failed to sign up, please try again” error

Tags: email, casperjs, mailgun, ghost-blog

I hope you are well.

I’m using Ghost 4.33 on DigitalOcean Droplet. The site is running well.

I have been editing the Casper theme. Mostly cosmetic updates.

I signed u pfor Mailgun and got my email, private password. etc. I followed number of guides to set up the email. but I still struggle to make it work. Not having any error log makes things reallydifficult.

I updated my
**config.production.json**

```
"mail": {
    "transport": "SMTP",
    "options": {
      "service": "Mailgun",
      "host": "smtp.mailgun.org",
      "port": 587,
      "secureConnection": true,
      "auth": {
        "user": "postmaster@blog.mywebsite.com",
        "pass": "mylooooooongpassword"
      }
    }
  },
```

I didnt make any change to Signup form. Im using the custom Casper form.

[image]

Any idea forthe solution? Thnak you , any help is greatly appreciated. stay safe.

I also updated the Settings with API.

[image]